# Does my stepdaughter have a way to tell I'm using Find My Device?

Tags: geolocation, location-services

Similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125921/does-my-son-know-im-using-find-my-iphone-when-i-log-on/125925) question for Apple, is there anything that my stepdaughter can look up or turn on that shows her I am currently checking her location using Find My Device such as notifications, a log, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a notification that will appear when you locate the device.

**WARNING**: This could prevent other notifications from appearing.

> To disable the notification, navigate to (**Version 8.1.0**, may be different on older versions)
>
> Settings -> Apps & notifications -> See all X apps -> Google Play services
>
> Under `Other`, disable `Uncategorized`

You should also be aware that there are applications that can fake the location of the phone, and that will effect Find My Device.

Comment: Is it the defaulted behavior to do so on the phone? Or do you have to enable the notification?

Comment: @pstatix The notification appearing is default behavior. As far as I am aware, there is no other way to disable the notification. I tried a few other ways, but nothing worked other than the remarks in my answer.

Comment: @pstatix if this answers your question, please mark it as such. If not, what more can I add to the answer for you to be satisfied?